# Delphi 2007 keyboard navigation - back to recent editor tab

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Below are listed some keyboard navigation shortcuts form D2007.

- <kbd>Shift+Alt+F11</kbd> moves focus to Structure view.
- <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F11</kbd> moves focus to Project Manager view.
- <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+b</kbd> moves focus to Breakpoints view.
- ...

Is it possible to get back to recent editor tab from above views (using keyboard only)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct shortcut mentioned in the official [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Default_Keyboard_Shortcuts) and also not [here](https://delphi.fandom.com/wiki/Default_IDE_Shortcut_Keys).

But what does work:

- Press <kbd>F12</kbd> once (if Form Designer is already visible) or twice
- <kbd>F11</kbd> alternates focus between Object Inspector, Form Designer and Code Editor